# CSS specificty issue

Tags: html, css

I have a nested div like this

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <div class="myOtherDiv">
```

In my CSS I want `myOtherDiv` to have `margin: 0 auto; but not myDiv`

If I write

```
.myDiv{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It applies to both with the specificty of 0,1,0

But

```
 .myDiv .myOtherDiv{
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Nothing happens. Which is weird, visual code reports the specificity of this to be 0,2,0 which is higher so should it not apply?

Comment: Having tested this, the CSS is fine - `.myDiv {` applies only to `myDiv`, whilst `.myDiv .myOtherDiv {` only applies to `myOtherDiv`, so I'm not sure what your issue is. Try it with something other than `margin: 0 auto;` (such as text `color` or `background-color`) and see what applies to where.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can see what it is that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided all of the CSS code it is hard to tell. However,

Issues with `margin: 0 auto;`
are you usually a result of the element not being a **block** element or contain a **width**.

Since `div` is a block element naturally, it takes up the entire width available even if you only have 1 letter inside that div(I.e `<div>A</div>`

You must declare a width before centering your div items.

So for example:

```
.myDiv {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Im regards to **specificity**,

If the **parent** `<div>` doesn't have a **width** assigned `margin:0 auto`will not do anything. However, if you assign a width then the block will not occupy all the page's space, and then the block itself is centered, but the items of the child div will not be centered or affected.

If you assign both the child and parent div `margin:0 auto` without either having a set **width** it will produce a null effect without affecting positioning at all because each block is just taking up all the space possible within the page.

If you want the child div block centered, then assign a width to the child div, and leave the parent div alone. Since the parent occupies all the page's width space, the child div will be centered on the page using `margin:0 auto;` and the width you assigned.

Comment: I may have missed the 'width' explanation. However, my answer is more readable. So at least for the sake of readability and understanding my answer doesn't deserve the downvote.

Comment: Actually if you have been working with CSS enough you should know that without setting a width, a block element can not be centered unless it is just text which in that case you use text-align: center.  In respect to specificity, you are correct - I failed tto address this and will do so now

Comment: If you take a look at my profile you'll see I know a lot about CSS. If the question is about giving a `div` a width for auto-margin to work, the question is a duplicate, and again shouldn't be answered, instead the built-in "vote/flag to close as a duplicate" should be used, so which ever is true, no answer should be posted.

Comment: @LGSon You have more SO experience than I do. I am just here to help folks, I suppose I've got some catching up in regards to the system in place and its containing rules and process. So, even if we had a short back and forth I respect your opinion and perspective of the matter.

Answer (score -1):

.myDiv .myOtherDiv {} or just .myOtherDiv {} should be good to target myOtherDiv.

Did you give the div a width? Block level elements like div's default to 100% widht of their parent. So you need to set a specific smaller width, or use `display: table;` so the content decides the width. See below:

```css
.myDiv{
  background: blue;
}
.myOtherDiv{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
   <div class="myOtherDiv">content
   </div>
 </div>
```